# Installing python library in databricks (Internet disabled)

Tags: python, azure, pip, databricks

In the databricks environtment the internet is disabled due to which we can't install library using pip install.

To overcome this we are following this process.

Dowloading the wheel file from pypi website manually. and then do

pip install wheel path

or

installing it manually in the cluster.

It is working fine with most of the packages where the package has less dependent on othere package. But in case of complex package let's say azure.idenity it has dependency on portloacker, msal extension and other hunderd of libraries. Now it is quite unmanageable and time consuming to download the all the dependent package and install it one by one.

Is there any way to do it? Any help will be really helpfull.

Note - The internet can't be enabled due to data security issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline